# Hibernate Composite Key Join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to use Spring Data to perform joined queries but one of my tables has a Composite Key and I'm not sure how to map the entities.

Here is an analogy of the data model:

```
table: device
pk=model_id
pk=serial_id
...

table: device_settings
pk=device_settings_id
fk=model_id
fk=serial_id
...
```

Here is an analogy of the code, which doesn't compile due to a "mappedby" attribute that is isn't present.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device_settings")
public class DeviceSettings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "device_settings_id")
    private Long id;

    // Pretty sure this is the problem
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Device.class, mappedBy = "deviceKey", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "model_id", referencedColumnName = "model_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "serial_id", referencedColumnName = "serial_id")})
    private List<Device> devices;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device {
    @Id
        private DeviceKey deviceKey;
    }
    ...
}


@Embeddable
public class DeviceKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1943684511893963184L;

    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private Long modelId;

    @Column(name = "serial_id")
    private Short serialId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn

To achieve your scenario you have to define @ManyToOne:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "model_id", referencedColumnName = "model_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "serial_id", referencedColumnName = "serial_id")})
     private Device device;
```

This will end up **model_id, serial_id, device_settings_id**

or

Define @JoinColumn in Device Entity
Entities:

**DeviceSettings** :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "device_settings")
    public class DeviceSettings {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "device_settings_id")
        private Long id;


        @OneToMany( mappedBy = "deviceSettings", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
         private List<Device> devices;
}
```

**Device Entity** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "device")
public class Device {

        @EmbeddedId
        private DeviceKey deviceKey;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="device_settings_id")
        private DeviceSettings deviceSettings;
       //getters and setters
}
```

Note : you can decide which is the owner of the relationship and put your mappings accorindly either One Device has many device settings or other way around.

Comment: Thanks, so that does compile but it leaves me wondering about how I can leverage Spring Data from the non-owner of the relationship...is the simple fact that I can call a .findOne() method on an entity combined with an eager fetch strategy going to always provide me with the ability to perform CRUD operations on either side? Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber yes thats right but still you can do with the LAZY fetch provided it has be taken care at the service level. Let us know if you have any difficulties.

Comment: I think I may be having a problem with the recursive nature of this mapping. If entities need to be persisted, and each one references the other, won't you be able to dive into the object in the debugger and see them infinitely referencing each other?

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber yes as mentioned earlier it depends on entity relationship and cascading operation.since cascading is only for merge it wont be a problem.i f you have any issue let us take it up in another question